# Copying text easily

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

am trying to copy text

as the above code shown

but its not working. can't copy text

thats the problem i have

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <span id="mytext">Hello World</span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
    
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("mytext");
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use select() for span tag,
the HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a  element or in an  element that includes a text field.
checkout this link for more information :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

this code will work if you already have input :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="mytext" size="20" value="Hello world!">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
         
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("mytext");
       copyText.select();
       document.execCommand("copy");
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

but if you want to copy span's text, first of all you should create an input element and then put the text in to element then select the text :
the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <span id="mytext">Hello World</span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
         
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var copyText = document.getElementById("mytext");
       var input= document.createElement("input");
       input.value = copyText.textContent;
       document.body.appendChild(input);
       input.select();
       document.execCommand("Copy");
       input.remove();
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```